# Wildfly 10 classloader hell (hibernate doesn't see Postgres Driver installed as module)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I use wildfly Entity Manager for my application, but besides that I need to establish jdbc connection in runtime for other purposes, so I receiving settings from service, in runtime, during application start and establish this connection.

I tried to use sql2o and it works just fine, but then I tried hibernate (I'm creating it programatically), and it didn't work. I took a look on internals and figured out why it doesn't work. 
When library calls DriverManager.getConnection() it checks callers ClassLoader. And when sql2o was loaded with an application just like Postgres Driver, the hibernate is not, and it fails.

creating of client sql2o that works just fine
[image]

creating hibernate programatically and it fails

[image]

Then I was trying to use PostgresDriver installed as Wildfly module and as deployment both ways didn't work. 
Furthermore I tried to extract hibernate from wildfly with jboss-deployment-structure.xml, and use bundled from my application. Again it doesn't work.
Every time I'm getting 
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql...

I found among registered drivers PostgresDriver loaded with Wildfly's 
with classloader id "org.postgres:main", when caller (hibernate's) ClassLoader
has id = "org.hibernate:main". So it's wildfly's modules, but why don't they see each other???

The problem:
[image]

I use ear packaging with 2 subdeployments (jar + war), how can I solve this problem, and make wildfly's hibernate see installed as wildfly module Postgres Driver?

Comment: could you attached some code ?

Comment: have added screenshots

Comment: why don't you use a datasource defined using cli? You can let hibernate and sql2o use a jdbc datasource instead of an url.

Comment: because i define url to database in runtime, during startup, performing http request to another service

Comment: You'd have to edit Hibernates `module.xml` to add a dependency to the `org.postgres` module if you want Hibernate to have visibility to the `org.postgres` module.